Using a map with template literal types throws error
I'm trying to follow the docs here.
Here's what I have:
enum InputFieldName {
    ReactionsCheckbox = 'reactionsEnabled',
    SettingsCheckbox = 'settingsEnabled',
}
type PropEventSource<Type> = `${string & keyof Type}Checkbox`;

const inputMap: Record<InputFieldName, PropEventSource<InputFieldName>> = {
    [InputFieldName.ReactionsCheckbox]: 'reactionsEnabledCheckbox',
    [InputFieldName.SettingsCheckbox]: 'settingsEnabledCheckbox',
}

const fieldName = inputMap[InputFieldName.ReactionsCheckbox]

console.log('fieldName', fieldName);

I correctly see reactionsEnabledCheckbox in the console, however I'm getting a typescript error:
Type of computed property's value is '"settingsEnabledCheckbox"',
  which is not assignable to type '"charAtCheckbox" | "charCodeAtCheckbox"
    | "concatCheckbox" | "indexOfCheckbox" | "lastIndexOfCheckbox"
        | "localeCompareCheckbox" | "matchCheckbox" | "replaceCheckbox" | ... 33 more ... | "valueOfCheckbox

How can I get this to work?
Also, prettier doesn't seem to see the following line as valid code:
type PropEventSource<Type> = `${string & keyof Type}Checkbox`;


Remove the keyof in your template literal type in order to use the actual enum values instead of their keys. Take a look at this playground. Does that address your question? If so I'll be happy to write up an explanation.

Your enum InputFieldName has values of type string. That means that keyof InputFieldName will give you the keys of a string (="charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" ...). Instead just use the actual enum type directly in your template literal type (`${string & Type}Checkbox`).
Note that you can always use an enum in a template literal type (e. g. type Permutations = `${MyEnum}`;. You only need an intersection with string (= & string) because the generic parameter Type has no constraint.
enum InputFieldName {
  ReactionsCheckbox = "reactionsEnabled",
  SettingsCheckbox = "settingsEnabled",
}
type PropEventSource<Type> = `${string & Type}Checkbox`;

const inputMap: Record<InputFieldName, PropEventSource<InputFieldName>> = {
  [InputFieldName.ReactionsCheckbox]: "reactionsEnabledCheckbox",
  [InputFieldName.SettingsCheckbox]: "settingsEnabledCheckbox",
};

const fieldName = inputMap[InputFieldName.ReactionsCheckbox];

TypeScript Playground
